# Object not appearing in final render

Tags: rendering

I'm new to Blender, and I really could use some help. I have a Blender project that looks horrible and won't render properly. When I go to the render tab and click render image, not the viewport rendering. There is an mp4 file in the project named TEST, and it will not show in the final render. I'm not sure if mp4 files just don't render in Blender or if it's just a bad mistake on my part. I would really appreciate some help with this problem. I've attached the blender project below. There is weird plane engine at the top of the editing space, just don't mind that.

[Blender File (Google Drive File)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iImHU_qzSzkgIxoNVRiWBaTioAl1Q7ju/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image objects are used in Blender as references, and never renders. To get Your image rendered, you have to set up a surface for it, set up the material with your file for this surface, set shading settings in the material (how image will be rendered, shaded or not etc.)

Likely there is a build-in add-on that can set all the settings for you, called *Import images as planes*. Enable it in user settings:

[image]

Then you can add renderable image to the scene using Shift + A → image → Images as planes:

[image]